# Raspberry Pi is shutting down during booting

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am very new to Raspberry Pi. I have Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, 8 GB RAM with Raspbian OS. I wanted to run the OpenCV video during the booting process. That is why I did some changes to rc.local. I have added

```
export DISPLAY=:0
sudo -H -u pi /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/script.py &
```

Booting set up: Desktop Autologin

It was working just fine. Then I wanted to destroy OpenCV video and then shutdown Pi with any key so I gave set:

```
 # Press any key to quit 
key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

if key > -1:
    call("sudo poweroff", shell=True)
    break
```

Now when I am booting the Pi, it is shutting down. I am not having a chance to make changes in my script. How can I get access to my Python script and edit my code?

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is setup you only have `1ms` to press a key, or `255` will be assign to `key`. Maybe remove the `0xFF` portion of the code and increase the time inside `waitKey()` to a better chance of capturing the key press.

From [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=waitkey#waitkey)

> The function waitKey waits for a key event infinitely (when \texttt{delay}\leq 0 ) or **for delay milliseconds, when it is positive**. **...** .It returns the code of the pressed key or -1 if no key was pressed before the specified time had elapsed.

> The function only works if there is at least one HighGUI window created and the window is active. If there are several HighGUI windows, any of them can be active.

If you are using Linux as host you can follow this instructions:

- Remove the SD Card from the Raspberry PI and insert on a Linux PC.
- Usually they automatically mount at least two partitions, [`boot`] and [`rootfs`].

  - If they are not automatically mounted use:
    `mount /dev/mmcblk0p2 /mnt/raspb-rootfs`

    The `mmcblk` part can vary depending on your SD Card adapter, you can use `dmesg` to check the adapter's name.
- Go to `/mnt/raspb-rootfs/etc/rc.local` and remove the script call.
- Insert the SD Card on the Raspberry Pi and the board should boot normally.